# The set of points that are twice as far from P(2, 0, 2) as they are from Q(1, 0, 3).

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

can you please check my solution for this question? I am getting a negative radius

The set of points that are twice as far from P(2, 0, 2) as they are from
Q(1, 0, 3).

attempt :

$$\sqrt{(x-2)^2 + (y-0)^2 + (z-2)^2} = 2 \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-0)^2 + (z-2)^2}$$

after simplification, i got

$$(x-4/3)^2 + y^2 + (z-10/3)^2 = - 172 / 81.$$

where did i make a mistake

Comment: You should have $\sqrt{(x-2)^2 + (y-0)^2 + (z-2)^2} = 2 \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-0)^2 + (z-3)^2}$, notice the $z-3$. Then square both sides to get $(x-2)^2 + (y-0)^2 + (z-2)^2 = 4 ((x-1)^2 + (y-0)^2 + (z-3)^2)$, then cancel like terms to get $(x-2)^2 + (z-2)^2 = 4(x-1)^2 + 3y^2 + 4(z-3)^2$, and expand the brackets.

Comment: i did the same thing. after simplification i got (x-2/3)^2+y ^2+(z-10/3)^2 = -172/81

Comment: Please show us your calculations so we can locate your error(s).

Comment: after simplification i got :   3$x^2$ -4x + 3$y^2$ + 3$z^2$ -20z + 32 =0              i did completing the square, i got: 3$(x-2/3)^2$ + 3$y^2$ + 3$(z-10/3)^2$ -4/9 - 100/9 + 288/9 = 0.  $(x-2/3)^2$ + $y^2$ + $(z-10/3)^2$ = -184/81

Comment: The left hand side of $(x - 2/3)^2 + y^2 + (z - 10/3)^2 = -172/81$ is correct.  You have not explained how you obtained $-172/81$.  Please show us your calculations.

Comment: 4($x^2$ -2x+1) + 3$y^2$ + 4($z^2$ -6z+9)-($x^2$ -4x +4)-($z^2$-4z+4) = 0 4$x^2$-8x+4+3$y^2$+4$z^2$-24z+36-$x^2$+4x-4-$z^2$+4z-4 = 0. After symplifiction, 3$x^2$-4x+3$y^2$+3$z^2$ -20z+32=0. i did completing the square, i got, 3$(x-2/3)^2$+3$y^2$+3$(z-10/3)^2$ -(4/9)-(100/9)+(288/9)=0. $(x-2/3)^2$ + $y^2$ + $(z-10/3)^2$ = -184/81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of points $(x, y, z)$ that are twice as far from $P(2, 0, 2)$ as they are from $Q(1, 0, 3)$ satisfy the equation
$$\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 0)^2 + (z - 2)^2} = 2\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 0)^2 + (z - 3)^2}$$
Squaring both sides yields
$$(x - 1)^2 + y^2 + (z - 2)^2 = 4[(x - 1)^2 + y^2 + (z - 3)^2]$$
Expanding and simplifying yields
\begin{align*}
x^2 - 2x + 1 + y^2 + z^2 - 4z + 4 & = 4(x^2 - 2x + 1 + y^2 + z^2 - 6z + 9)\\
x^2 - 2x + 1 + y^2 + z^2 - 4z + 4 & = 4x^2 - 8x + 4 + 4y^2 + 4z^2 - 24z + 36\\
-32 & = 3x^2 - 4x + 3y^2 + 3z^2 - 20z
\end{align*}
If we divide both sides of the equation by $3$, we obtain
$$-\frac{32}{3} = x^2 - \frac{4}{3}x + y^2 + z^2 - \frac{20}{3}z$$
Completing the squares yields
\begin{align*}
-\frac{32}{3} + \frac{4}{9} + \frac{100}{9} & = \left(x^2 - \frac{4}{3}x + \frac{4}{9}\right) + y^2 + \left(z^2 - \frac{20}{3} + \frac{100}{9}\right)\\
-\frac{96}{9} + \frac{4}{9} + \frac{100}{9} & = \left(x - \frac{2}{3}\right)^2 + y^2 + \left(z - \frac{10}{3}\right)^2
\end{align*}
**Note:**  You chose not to divide by $3$ once you obtained
$$3x^2 - 4x + 3y^2 + 3z^2 - 20z = -32$$
That means you must multiply the number you added inside the parentheses by $3$ in order to balance the equation.
\begin{align*}
3\left(x^2 - \frac{4}{3}x\right) + 3y^2 + 3\left(z^2 - \frac{20}{3}z\right) & = -32\\
3\left(x^2 - \frac{4}{3} + \frac{4}{9}\right) + 3\left(z^2 - \frac{20}{3}z + \frac{100}{9}\right) & = -32 + 3 \cdot \frac{4}{9} + 3 \cdot \frac{100}{9}\\
3\left(x - \frac{2}{3}\right)^2 + 3y^2 + 3\left(z - \frac{10}{3}\right)^2 & = -32 + \frac{4}{3} + \frac{100}{3}\\
3\left(x - \frac{2}{3}\right)^2 + 3y^2 + 3\left(z - \frac{10}{3}\right)^2 & = -\frac{96}{3} + \frac{4}{3} + \frac{100}{3}\\
3\left(x - \frac{2}{3}\right)^2 + 3y^2 + 3\left(z - \frac{10}{3}\right)^2 & = \frac{8}{3}\\
\left(x - \frac{2}{3}\right)^2 + y^2 + \left(z - \frac{10}{3}\right)^2 & = \frac{8}{9}
\end{align*}
which agrees with the result obtained above.

Answer (score 1):

You did not give us the lines of your solution, and we cannot say where exactly is the error. But the correct right hand side is $8/9$.

Comment: 4($x^2$ -2x+1) + 3$y^2$ + 4($z^2$ -6z+9)-($x^2$ -4x +4)-($z^2$-4z+4) = 0 4$x^2$-8x+4+3$y^2$+4$z^2$-24z+36-$x^2$+4x-4-$z^2$+4z-4 = 0. After symplifiction, 3$x^2$-4x+3$y^2$+3$z^2$ -20z+32=0. i did completing the square, i got, 3$(x-2/3)^2$+3$y^2$+3$(z-10/3)^2$ -(4/9)-(100/9)+(288/9)=0. $(x-2/3)^2$ + $y^2$ + $(z-10/3)^2$ = -184/81

Comment: @patriciajade It should be $-3\frac{4}{9}-3\frac{100}{9}$, not $-\frac{4}{9}-\frac{100}{9}$.

Comment: -24z + 4z = -20z not 16z